# How to ignore file with .<numberic>.ext in git?

Tags: regex, git

I have a list of  file in my project:

For example:

```
 1. src/index.1.js
 2. src/screens/index.1.js
 3. src/screens/index.2.js
```

I want to ignore all the files having the numeric number.

I have tried using `**/*.1.*` ,  `**/*.2.*`. Is there a way to ignore all the file with numeric value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git uses [glob pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) to match ignored files. Use the following to ignore all such above-mentioned files (with multi-digit numbers also).

```
**/*.[0-9]*.js
```

Comment: Be aware that this will also match, e.g., `dir/file.3a.js`. As long as that is OK (it probably is) this is a suitable pattern.

Comment: @torek: yeah that's why I have decided to go via the `find` command as it is not possible to define an exact pattern that would take into account only several digits...

Comment: @pankaj Thank you, it is what I needed.  But like torek said, it also ignores 1doc.js file but that's ok. I will mark this as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range. For your example:

```
**/*.[0-9].js
```

Would match a js file in any directory that ends with .(number).js

Comment: however how do you take into account when there is more than one digit in the filename? anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run the following `find` command after eventually adapting the `\.js` part if you do not want to take into account only the `.js` files:

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*\/.*\.[0-9]\+\.js'
./src/screens/index.2.js
./src/screens/index.123.js
./src/index.1.js
```

when you find all the files you are interested in, change your find command into:

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*\/.*\.[0-9]\+\.js' -exec git checkout {} \;
```

to checkout those files.